# Read joomla user information from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, joomla

I've a problem with a php script that accept POST request from an android client that send username and password to the script.
First it connect to the Joomla mySQL database and then read the user information.

This is the php code:

```
<?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) ); 
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); 

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' ); 
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' ); 

require('libraries/joomla/factory.php'); 

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site'); 
$mainframe->initialise(); 

$user =& JFactory::getUser();

$credentials = array();
$options = array();

$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 

$name = $input->get('username', null); 
$pass = $input->get('password', null);

$credentials['username'] = $name;
$credentials['password'] = $pass;

$result = False;
$result=JFactory::getApplication()->login($credentials,$options);

echo $fn;
echo $ln;

if ($result==False) {
    $Log = "Not logged";}
else{
    $Log = "Logged";}

$user->get('name');

$arr = array ('Statement'=>$Log,'User'=>$user);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I've used 'echo $fn' to check the POST connection and it works but it return me all the voices of json to null.

If I write my username and password into the php it works perfectly, if I use GET request the first time it return me json to null, the second time works.

Thanks.

Comment: don't use `$_POST['....']` in Joomla. Have a read of this: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: Thanks @Lodder
I've used :`$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 
$name = $input->get('username', null); 
$pass = $input->get('password', null);`
But it returns a json null.

Comment: Are you trying to get the username and password once a new user has registered or from the current user that is logged in? Can you please update your question with your update `$input->get` method. Oh and just on a side note, you can remove the `&` operator before `JFactory` ;)

Comment: With a logged user it works without problem but I want that it takes the login and then write the user's information.